# When I create a mutable array it is saying I have a regular array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Initially my array "items" was initialized using NSArray - I realized that when I transferred the data in the array to webpodnew mutable array that it wasn't mutable. So I went back and changed my array items to NSMutableArray - this didn't seem to change anything. I've tried creating a new mutable array using arrayWithArray: and [mutableCopy] but it doesn't seem to work, or it will be an empty array with key values/pairs instead of objects. The reason I want a mutable array is because I need to remove some null items from said array.

```
NSDictionary *PageItem = [xml objectForKey:@"channel"];
NSMutableArray *items = [PageItem objectForKey:@"item"];
NSMutableArray *webpodnew = [items valueForKeyPath:@"enclosure._url"];

[webpodnew removeObjectAtIndex:3];
```

Please let me know what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code where are you creating the mutable array.

Comment: `objectForKey` returns type `id`, this means for compiler any objective-c type. So there is no type checking during compilation and complier just assumes that you are known what are you doing. Your xml simply contains none mutable arrays.

Comment: Declaring a pointer to be of a certain class does not make the object that class.

Comment: how do I remove null items from an array then if i cant change it to a mutable array

Comment: You have to copy the array to a mutable array, then operate on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
[PageItem objectForKey:@"item"];
```

You have a typo:

```
[PageItem objectForKey:@"items"];
```

If that doesn't work, please NSLog the dictionary to see what it actually contains, and show us it.

**Edit**

You also have a couple other errors: you can't do `valueForKeyPath` on an array. Try this instead of your current code:

```
NSDictionary *PageItem = [xml objectForKey:@"channel"];
NSDictionary *items = [PageItem objectForKey:@"items"];
NSArray *array = [items valueForKeyPath:@"enclose._url"];
NSMutableArray *webpodnew = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

[webpodnew removeObjectAtIndex:3];
```

Comment: A cast doesn't magically convert an immutable array into a mutable one.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If `PageItem[@"items"]` is referencing an `NSArray` then the array is immutable regardless of the cast and regardless of the type of variable you assign it to.

Comment: @rmaddy My bad, I thought it was the other way around. I've added the correct method.

Comment: NSArray *items = [PageItem objectForKey:@"item"];
        NSMutableArray *itemnew = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:items];
        NSMutableArray *webpodnew = [itemnew valueForKeyPath:@"enclosure._url"];

Comment: I just did this but it is still saying webpodnew is a regular array

Comment: It seems to be transferring only key/value pairs if the array is mutable but objects if it isnt

Comment: @mnka `NSMutableArray *webpodnew = [items valueForKeyPath:@"enclosure._url"];` isn't going to work because items is an array, not a dictionary. There are no key paths in an array.

Comment: You can call `-valueForKey:` and `-valueForKeyPath:` on arrays. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) say that `-valueForKey:` constructs an array by forwarding the call to each item in the array. The [docs for `-valueForKeyPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-CJBIIIEB) say that it chains a series of calls to `-valueForKey:`.

Comment: @KenThomases I know that you can do that on just about any `NSObject`, but I don't think that was OP's intention.

Comment: I wasn't addressing the OP's intention. I was addressing your incorrect assertion that you couldn't do it, both in your answer and your comment replying to mnka.

Comment: @KenThomases So, it calls valueForKey on each object in the array?

Comment: Yes, that's what `-valueForKey:` does when sent to an array. `-valueForKeyPath:` is built on top of `-valueForKey:` to iteratively apply each component of the key path.

Comment: for some reason the array wont copy to a mutable is really the main issue